# Two cxGrids: cxGridDBTableView1 applies only to one grid?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I have two cxgrid's on my form (cxGrid1 and cxGrid2).
Both have the  NewItemRow.Visible.

Now, I want to remove NewItemRow from cxGrid2.
Calling :

```
cxGridDBTableView1.NewItemRow.Visible:=False;
```

removes NewItemRow from cxGrid1 and not from the one I want (cxGrid2).
How can I apply this to cxGrid2 ?

Comment: FWIW: Have you tried [DevEx support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/List/1)? IMHO it's the best place for DevEx problems.

Comment: Three questions in two hours? Maybe you need to contact the two vendors or read some tutorials or documentation. It certainly doesn't appear you're putting sufficient effort into finding an answer yourself first before posting here.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your code "cxGridDBTableView1.NewItemRow.Visible".  If your grids are named cxGrid1 and cxGrid2, their TableViews will be called cxGrid**1**DBTableView1 and cxGrid**2**DBTableView1.  Neither of them will be called "cxGridDBTableView1".

Comment: @Ken White - I did about a 3 hours search on this one before posting. And am still at it.

Comment: Three hours is not *sufficient effort*. I typically spend **days** researching and trying to solve an issue before I even consider asking a question here, and then I make myself do more research while I'm composing and writing my question. Three questions in two hours means a max of 40 minutes each trying to solve them. That's an indication of *I'm not going to bother trying to figure this out. Somebody at SO will do the work for me.*.

Comment: @MartynA - You cant do views like you mention because you get the error : [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(367): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'cxGrid2DBTableView1'.

Comment: Excuse me?  I just have, and it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @Ken White - days...ehh Ken, me too.... Then google ends me up in a loop where I start seeing already seen stuff etc. Tiring...Actually I think I have read somewhere on devex forum that this can not be resolved,or something like it,I am not sure.

Comment: @MartynA - I have just posted you the compiler error. What do you mean it runs fine ? What have you written that I have not ?cxGrid2DBTableView1.NewItemRow.Visible:=False;?Even adding a : var cxGrid2DBTableView1:TcxGridtableView; wont compile.It does work if you have only one grid. Two,no.

Comment: It seems a : var AView: TcxGridDBTableView; applies only to one grid.

Comment: "It seems a : var AView: TcxGridDBTableView;"  You should not need or have a var declaration like that unless you are creating your grids and their subcomponents entirely in code - compare with the declarations in my answer.  Btw, readers shouldn't have to guess how your form is declared, this info should be in your q.

Comment: Btw, the fact that you get an undeclared identifier error at line **362** seems to me to confirm that there is a mistake in the declaration of your form.  "It does work if you have only one grid. Two,no"  Sorry, you are completely wrong - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious from your q and your replies to readers' comments that there is something amiss in the declaration of your form.  A newly created form with cxGrids placed on it in the usual way (by selecting the cxGrid on the Component Palette and dropping two instances of it onto the form) does not exhibit the compilation problem, nor the aberrant behaviour you describe.  Try it and you will see what I mean.

Below is the code and .DFM extract of a project which has two TcxGrids, one with a visible
NewItemRow, one without.  This example project is for D7 using v.15 of the cxGrid, which is the
highest version number which supports D7.  I've done it in D7 as you didn't say what Delphi version you are using.

I've deliberately set up as many of the component properties, etc, as I could in code, so you
can see what is going on and how it is done.

If you try it, you will find that it compiles without the error message you mention
in one of your comments and behaves as intended.  Therefore I can only assume that there is some
error in your naming or declaration of components and/or in your code that we readers can't see in what you've included in your q.

The best I can suggest you do to unravel your problem is to start with a blank form and drop 2 cxGrids onto it.  Save and view the resulting DFM and confirm to yourself that the 2cxGrids and their subcomponents (cxGridDBTableView and cxGridLevel) are correctly **and** distinctly named, and then do a DIFF between that DFM and your project's one to identify where they diverge.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView;
    cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel;
    cxGrid1: TcxGrid;
    cxGrid2DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView;
    cxGrid2Level1: TcxGridLevel;
    cxGrid2: TcxGrid;
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    DBNavigator2: TDBNavigator;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    CDS1ID: TIntegerField;
    CDS1Name: TStringField;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;
[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Field : TField;
begin
  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'ID';
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'Name';
  Field.Size := 20;
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  CDS1.InsertRecord([1, 'One']);

  DBNavigator1.DataSource := DataSource1;
  DBNavigator2.DataSource := DataSource1;

  cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.DataSource := DataSource1;
  cxGrid2DBTableView1.DataController.DataSource := DataSource1;

  //  The following creates default columns for the grids
  cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems;
  cxGrid2DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems;

  cxGrid1DBTableView1.NewItemRow.Visible:= True;
  cxGrid2DBTableView1.NewItemRow.Visible:= False;

end;
```

DFM extract

```
object Form1: TForm1
  [...]
  object cxGrid1: TcxGrid
    Left = 24
    Top = 16
    Width = 250
    Height = 200
    TabOrder = 0
    object cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView
      Navigator.Buttons.CustomButtons = <>
      DataController.DataSource = DataSource1
      DataController.KeyFieldNames = 'ID'
      DataController.Summary.DefaultGroupSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.FooterSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.SummaryGroups = <>
    end
    object cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel
      GridView = cxGrid1DBTableView1
    end
  end
  object cxGrid2: TcxGrid
    Left = 32
    Top = 280
    Width = 250
    Height = 200
    TabOrder = 1
    object cxGrid2DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView
      Navigator.Buttons.CustomButtons = <>
      DataController.DataSource = DataSource1
      DataController.KeyFieldNames = 'ID'
      DataController.Summary.DefaultGroupSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.FooterSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.SummaryGroups = <>
    end
    object cxGrid2Level1: TcxGridLevel
      GridView = cxGrid2DBTableView1
    end
  end
  object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
    Left = 40
    Top = 232
    Width = 240
    Height = 25
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object DBNavigator2: TDBNavigator
    Left = 40
    Top = 496
    Width = 240
    Height = 25
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object CDS1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = CDS1
  end
```

Comment: must be the heat....yes you are right... I was failing to see the naming conventions of the views.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.